# Unable to register chrome as default web-browser

Tags: python, webbrowser-control

Here is the code:

```
import webbrowser
from webbrowser import register
    
chrome_path = "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx4- 
browser_files_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15788.0_none_030e6fac24eb4365"
webbrowser.register('google-chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.get('google-chrome').open("https://www.facebook.com/", new=0,autoraise=False)  #No Output
```

I'm unable to register chrome as default web-browser. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path of your chrome is wrong, it should look like this :

```
import webbrowser
from webbrowser import register
    
chrome_path = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('google-chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.get('google-chrome').open("https://www.facebook.com/", new=0,autoraise=False)  #No Output
```